# Laravel 5 Pass and get a flash data not working

Tags: laravel, session, laravel-5

i want to pass a flash data from store function to add function but i cant get it to work, i always get null;

here is my controller

```
public function add()
{
    return view('cars.add');
}

public function store(CarFormRequest $request)
{
    $car = new Cars(array(
        'name' => $request->get('name'),
        'color_id' => $request->get('color')
    ));

    $car->save();
    $car->position_id = $car->id;
    $car->save();

    return redirect('/cars/add')->with('status', 'A Car has been added');
}
```

here is my view:

```
@if (session('status'))
    <div class="alert alert-success">
        {{ session('status') }}
    </div>
@endif
```

Comment: Try this http://github.com/digitlimit/alert

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add in your controller

```
session()->flash('status', 'Task was successful!');
```

and in View:

```
@if (session->has('status'))
    <div class="alert alert-success">
        {{ session('status') }}
    </div>
@endif
```

Comment: it worked thanks? do you have any idea why my first code wasn't working?

Comment: You've set a session in your controller. You just passed a variable to your view.